# Removing the contents of /dev/mapper/vg_ volume when 100%

Tags: linux, centos, volume, mapper

On a CentOS Linux box, when I run the following:

```
df-h
```

I get that `vg_name-1v_root` is at 100%.

```
Filesystem                      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_name-lv_root     12G   12G     0 100% /
```

When I drill down to `/dev/mapper` it looks like this `vg_name-1v_root` is a soft link to `../dm-0`.

However i'm not able to get into `vg_name-1v_root` or the `../dm-0` directories.

I am able to run `lsblk`, `vgs` and `lvs` to view the volume, but cannot enter it or view the contents.

I've spent some time googling and searching Stack Overflow. How can I delete or even view what's in the directory `/dev/mapper/vg_name-1v_root`?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Updated formatting, title and tags.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at the wrong column in the `df` output. That's a device, not a directory. In the `Mounted on` column, you see that the device is mounted on `/`, the root directory. It contains all of the files that aren't under any other mount point - your `/bin`, your `/etc`, your `/lib`, and depending on your setup, maybe your `/usr`, `/tmp`, `/home`... anything at the top level that you don't see listed separately in the output of `df` or `mount`.

To find out what's taking up space on that filesystem, you can run `du` from the root directory, using the `-x` option to prevent it from crossing into other filesystems.

```
cd /
du -x
```